# How to create AWS EC2 instance shared folders

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-ec2, shared-libraries, share

A Dobut, how to create sharable folders between two EC2 windows systems?

And how to create a share folder in two Linux machine?

Is the only option for Linux is EFS and windows is FSx?

I couldn't find a way, can anybody help.

I tried with enabling proper ports in security groups, and made the discovery on in network and security in windows. But no results.

Comment: EFS and FSx would be my answers to this.  Why don't they work for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of shared folders? Based on that you can use services.
There is also a feature called *EBS multi* attach where you can attach the **same *io1/io2 type ebs* volume to different ec2 in same AZ**.

EFS for linux is pay per gb used. It costs roughly <$2 for 10 GB/Month. FSx is bit costly.

Check which one suits your needs & decide.